# Why is the screen shared with me over skype is so small?

Tags: 10.10, skype

My colleague and me are often using skype to work together, but there is a problem that bothers me very much. When he is sharing his whole screen, I only receive it in a window that takes about a fourth part of my screen (about 50% size). Obviously, all text becomes unreadable.

We have the same horizontal resolution, but I have a 4:3 display, and he has a 16:9 display. So it's 1280x1024 against 1280x768, his screen should be able to fit into mine.

What's even stranger is that when I use a laptop I have, the screen is shared with me at 100% size. Both my PC and my laptop use Ubuntu 10.10.

Can something be done about it?

P.S. Maybe it has something to do with `compiz`?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you maximize the video-window?

The fact that for some users/on other computers the video-window is maximized by default could be a saved preference from your last session.

Comment: Yes, I can maximize the window, but when it is maximized, it looks as if you stretch a bad quality picture to twice its size - the displayed text still remains unreadable.

Comment: Have you tried closing the window when it is maximized? If my theory is correct and Skype saves the window preferences. It should on the next call be opened maximised and perhaps have a non-stretched good quality.

Comment: Yes, I have just tried it and it still opens with the same restricted size and the same bad quality.